# Broaden part of a sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, scale

I like to make a shape that is egg like, meaning broadening the lower part of a sphere but keep the upper part the same (and not narrow it like an egg).
I know you can scale a UV sphere on a certain axis, but that narrows/broadens it all together.
Is there a way to scale only a part of the sphere and keep it rather smooth?

This is my first question here so I hope I am coherent enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edit mode, you can select the vertices that you want to scale the most (those that will be the widest part) then turn on proportional editing. Press S to scale, and use the mouse wheel to control the radius of influence.